# How do I force Breadcrumb to use a menu other than Main Menu?

Tags: 7, routes, breadcrumbs

I am trying to force breadcrumb to follow the structure of a menu other than Main Menu.

I have configured the content type to use the new menu to add links, which are displayed correctly in the sidebar menu. However breadcrumb just displays Home > (current_page).

Where is this configured? Is it hard coded?

Any advice appreciated.

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Menu Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb)

By default, Drupal will use the Navigation menu for the breadcrumb. This module allows you to use the menu the current page belongs to for the breadcrumb.

As an added bonus, it also allows you to Append the page title to the breadcrumb (either as a clickable url or not) and hide the breadcrumb if it only contains the link to the front page.

Comment: This is of course the correct answer. Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Then you should mark it as correct. :)

Comment: I thought I had... obviously not. Now marked as correct. Thanks again.